# pspnetのコードを実装する際に表示されるエラーの理由がわかりません。

Tags: python, 画像認識

pspnetを実装しようとしているのですが、pspnetのエンコーダ部分で2048のチャンネル数を求められているのに実際は1024のチャンネル数で一致しないというエラーが表示され、この問題についてパラメータを変更したりインターネットで調べてみたのですが、結局わからなかったです。どこが原因なのでしょうか。
回答お願いします。

見づらくて申し訳ないのですが、エラー文は一番下の方にあります。

```
class PyramidModule(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, sizes=(1, 2, 3, 6)):
        super(PyramidModule, self).__init__()
        self.stages = nn.ModuleList([self._make_stage(in_channels, size) for size in sizes])
        self.conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels * (len(sizes) + 1), out_channels, kernel_size=1)

    def _make_stage(self, in_channels, size):
        prior = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=(size, size))
        conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, in_channels // 4, kernel_size=1, bias=False)
        return nn.Sequential(prior, conv)

    def forward(self, x):
        h, w = x.size(2), x.size(3)
        priors = [F.interpolate(stage(x), size=(h, w), mode='bilinear', align_corners=True) for stage in self.stages]
        priors.append(x)
        output = self.conv(torch.cat(priors, 1))
        return output
    
class ResNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, block, layers, num_classes=1000, zero_init_residual=True):
        super(ResNet, self).__init__()
        self.inplanes = 128

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=7, stride=2, padding=3, bias=False)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(64)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace = True)
        self.maxpool = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size = 3 , stride = 2 , padding = 1)
        
        self.layer1 = self._make_layer(block , 64 , layers[0] , stride = 1)
        self.layer2 = self._make_layer(block , 128 , layers[1] , stride = 2)
        self.layer3 = self._make_layer(block , 256 , layers[2] , stride = 2)
        self.layer4 = self._make_layer(block , 512 , layers[3] , stride = 2)
  
    def _make_layer(self, block, planes, blocks, stride=1):
        downsample = None
        if stride != 1 or self.inplanes != planes * block.expansion:
            downsample = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Conv2d(self.inplanes, planes * block.expansion, kernel_size=1, stride=stride, bias=False),
                nn.BatchNorm2d(planes * block.expansion),
            )

        layers = []
        layers.append(block(self.inplanes, planes, stride, downsample))
        self.inplanes = planes * block.expansion
        for _ in range(1, blocks):
            layers.append(block(self.inplanes, planes))

        return nn.Sequential(*layers)
    
class PSPNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, block, layers, num_classes=1000, zero_init_residual=True):
        super(PSPNet, self).__init__()
        self.resnet = ResNet(block, layers, num_classes=num_classes, zero_init_residual=zero_init_residual)

        psp_out_channels = 512 
        decoder_out_channels = 256
        self.pyramid = PyramidModule(2048, psp_out_channels)
        self.final_conv = nn.Conv2d(decoder_out_channels, num_classes, kernel_size=1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.resnet.conv1(x)
        x = self.resnet.bn1(x)
        x = self.resnet.relu(x)
        x = self.resnet.maxpool(x)

        x = self.resnet.layer1(x)
        x = self.resnet.layer2(x)
        x = self.resnet.layer3(x)
        x = self.resnet.layer4(x)
        
        x = self.pyramid(x)
        x = self.final_conv(x)

        return x
```

追加した部分です

```
batch_size = 32
num_epochs = 10
learning_rate = 0.001


model = PSPNet(Bottleneck, [3,4,6,3])

criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for images, labels in train_df_loader:
        images = images.to(device)
        labels = labels.to(device)

        optimizer.zero_grad()

        outputs = model(images)

        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        print(f"Epoch [{epoch+1}/{num_epochs}], Loss: {loss.item():.4f}")

torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'pspnet_model.pth')
```

エラー内容

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-8404aaecff27> in <cell line: 6>()
     11         optimizer.zero_grad()
     12 
---> 13         outputs = model(images)
     14 
     15         loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py in _conv_forward(self, input, weight, bias)
    457                             weight, bias, self.stride,
    458                             _pair(0), self.dilation, self.groups)
--> 459         return F.conv2d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
    460                         self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
    461 

RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [512, 2048, 1, 1], expected input[16, 1024, 1, 1] to have 2048 channels, but got 1024 channels instead
```

Comment: エラーメッセージに書かれた問題発生個所である`13`行目を含む部分のソースコードが提示されていません。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に質問内容をブラッシュアップしてください。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: すみません。該当部分を追加しましたので確認お願いします。

Comment: importするライブラリ/モジュールや使うデータをどう用意するか等も含めて、他者が問題を再現・調査するのに十分な情報と、分断されていない完結したソースコードを提示してください。あとこんな記事が参考になるもしれません。[PyTorchでよくあるエラーの対処方法(次元やチャンネル数)](https://yukr.hatenablog.com/entry/2020/05/03/170502)